# Equations solving in AutoLayout

Tags: ios, autolayout

I have this code and I would like to know how the equations are being solved here:

```
-(viewDidAppear){
self.view.autoresizingMask=NO;
NSLayoutConstraint *layouts1 = [NSLayoutConstraint  constraintWithItem:_redView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:_yellowView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth multiplier:3.0f constant:0];
[self.view addConstraint:layouts1];


NSLayoutConstraint *layouts2 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_yellowView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:_redView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth multiplier:2.0f constant:50];
[self.view addConstraint:layouts2];
}
```

When I solve these equations to get a common solution,I get the values    -10 and -30 but when I'm getting some width for yellowView and nothing for redView.I have tried almost everything to get this working now,but I'm not able to trace the behaviour of auto layout.
I was wondering how these equations are solved?

[image: Constraint1]
   [image: Constraint2]

Comment: Now can you tell me the solution of these equations?

Comment: What is this negative vote for?I have worked hard for this.

Comment: I can only see the yellow view.From what I have studied ,two equations will be formed and then a common solution is derived.But it ain't showing what I'm expecting.

Comment: I will ......in a couple of minutes!!!

Comment: you give a constraints with storyboard and change width constraint of that view?

Comment: Yes .....I'm trying to explore auto layout here and this is the beginning for me.I'm trying to change the widths here.I just want to know the behaviour here.Why am I able to see only yellowView in the output?How is the redView disappearing?

Comment: You are not getting me.....I am not trying to get the output here.What I'm trying to understand here is the behaviour.Please check the title of my post.Can you solve these equations?

Answer (score 0):

Atlast I got it.It takes the width of yellow view as the unknown and calculates it because the leading of yellow view depends on the red view.So the equation will be something like this:

```
Wr = Wy*3 + 0;
50 = Wy*3;
Wy = 16.66;
```